# Espresso tests failing to record intent when trying to check if an intent is sent

Tags: testing, android-intent, android-activity, integration-testing, android-espresso

I'm trying to use Espresso for integration testing for a AdjustableWebView class that I've created.

My test looks like this:

```
@Test
public void myTest() {
        // intents.init() is done in the @Before setup() method
        
        // ... some code to set up permissions correctly
        
        // ensure that the activity doesn't actually open
        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        Intent contentIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult contentResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, contentIntent);
        Instrumentation.ActivityResult chooserResult = new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, chooserIntent);
        intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT)).respondWith(contentResult);
        intending(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)).respondWith(chooserResult);

        // ... some code to load page in webview

        // ... some code to click on the proper element in the webview

        // verify
        intended(anyOf(hasAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT), hasAction(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER)));

        // intents.release() is done in the @After teardown() method
}
```

My result is this:

```
IntentMatcher: (has action: is "android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" or has action: is "android.intent.action.CHOOSER")

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
    at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1736)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.AssertionErrorHandler.handleSafely(AssertionErrorHandler.java:3)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.AssertionErrorHandler.handleSafely(AssertionErrorHandler.java:1)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$TypedFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:4)
    at androidx.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:5)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:5)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:12)
    at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:188)
    at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.intended(Intents.java:167)
    at com.mypackage.myapp.webview.tests.AdjustableWebViewTests.testFileInput_intentLaunches(AdjustableWebViewTests.java:246)
    ... 35 trimmed
Caused by: junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: Wanted to match 1 intents. Actually matched 0 intents.

IntentMatcher: (has action: is "android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" or has action: is "android.intent.action.CHOOSER")

Matched intents:[]

Recorded intents:[]
    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
    at androidx.test.espresso.intent.VerificationModes$Times.verify(VerificationModes.java:80)
    at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents.internalIntended(Intents.java:344)
    at androidx.test.espresso.intent.Intents$2.check(Intents.java:192)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAssertion.check(ViewInteraction.java:2)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:10)
    at androidx.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$2.call(ViewInteraction.java:1)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7656)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

I put in log statements and am able to verify that my code starts an activity using `startActivityForResult` and is providing an `ACTION_CHOOSER` intent to the activity, but for some reason, whatever I do, I am unable to record the intent, and my test fails. Even if I remove the `intending` lines and let the activity open normally, and I can verify that the correct intent is created (using Log statements), an activity opens correctly, and the result code passed in onActivityResult is `RESULT_CANCELLED` (once again, verified using Log statements), but still, I cannot record the intent.

Would someone be able to point me in the right direction in terms of how I would fix this? I don't want to check the activity that opens because I want to keep my implementation as generic as possible (all I want to check is that SOME intent is sent out and I know there will be SOME activity to deal with it but I'm not specifying which activity is doing that work).

I have looked at several StackOverflow posts but nothing has been helping :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My exact situation was that I was trying to click on an HTML input tag and then record the intent. I was using Espresso. A colleague of mine helped me with this, and was able to get the test working by using UIAutomator instead of Espresso.